# Fermat's Last Theorem And Modular Arithmetic

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

I was browsing Reddit yesterday when stumbled upon an [interesting math problem](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/7vi6h6/i_created_a_smart_contract_for_fermats_last/): a user tried to implement a "smart contract" that was irredeemable under the validity of Fermat's Last Theorem.

However, the author did not account of the use of int256, leading to this [solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/7vi6h6/i_created_a_smart_contract_for_fermats_last/dtui0z8/). Thus the attacker was able to find a combination of $a, b, c, n > 2$ such that

$a^n + b^n = c^n \pmod{2^{256}}$

held true.

My questions then are:

1. Is Fermat's Last Theorem always invalid in finite spaces? What does this have to do with the so-called [freshmen's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freshman%27s_dream)?
2. How was the attacker able to find values of $b, c, n > 2$ so fast? I thought the difficulty of such a problem would involve tangentially the discrete logarithm assumption.

Comment: It had be proven that for polynomials $f$ of degree greater than $2$  the fact that $f=0$ modulo all natural integers does not imply that $f=0$ in $\mathbb Z$. If I remember correctly a famous Selmer's example is $3x^3+4y^3+5z^3=0$.